# ios - Enterprise app with more than resource files of size 2GB

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm working on an ipad application for enterprise distribution (that will be used only by my company people)
It has many video files, images, pdf's etc. after making the app, the size of the ipa is around 2.2 GB.
I'd like to know whether the app will run effectively on all iPad's or will it be trouble to do so?
Looking forward for some solution where it won't effect the performance of the app

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you stay under 2GB, it should definitely work for all devices, since the maximum limit of an app on the AppStore is 2GB.

Since you you distribute internally, it should theoretically also work with a larger file, like 2.2GB as you mention.

Most iPads should have FAT32 file system (or better) which sets the physical limit to 4GB. However I don't know if there exist iPads with a FAT16 file system, if it does, their limit is 2GB!

However, I would not recommend having such a large app bundle. Instead I would use a small app bundle and let the users download the content from inside the application from a company server.

If you need to have offline support, you could provide bundles or packages for the users to download into their apps, and save them there (preferably smaller than 2 gb each).

There are many good reasons for this:

- What if you need to release an update for your app? Do your really want to force your users to download a new 2GB bundle just for an upgrade?
- What if you want to add more content? Wouldn't it be better if the users could download this from inside the app?
- You can let your users download the content in steps (an app bundle needs to be downloaded completely at once)
- Let your users choose what content they need to download
- Let your users use the app while content is being downloaded
- and more...

Comment: I agree with you. How can I find whether iPad 2 has FAT 16 or FAT 32? How about iPad3?

Comment: Ipad2 and 3 most likely does not have FAT16. I doubt even iPad1 has it on any of its memory sizes. I tried to google for it but couldn't find any info so I couldn't give you any promises on iPad1. But on 2 and 3 you should be safe...

Comment: When I'm installing my 2.5 GB app on iPad1, its not installing. I thought the reason might be FAT16. Unfortunately I don't have iPad2/3 with me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend pulling *what you need* from your servers *when it's needed*, (since I assume most of these files currently reside on your servers anyway), then discarding it when you don't need it.

I wouldn't include anything in the build of your app that can be included at a later time.

Comment: This is not server based. Its static app which shows the products of the company, info about the company etc.

Comment: So all the product data isn't stored in a database on a server... where is it then, Word files lol?

Comment: You could still place your company info on a server and let it be downloaded into the app. Either file-by-file or in packages or similar. I stated some reasons in my answer why this might be a better solution in the end.