# Why can't my program save a large amount (>2GB) to a file?

Tags: c, large-files

I am having trouble trying to figure out why my program cannot save more than 2GB of data to a file. I cannot tell if this is a programming or environment (OS) problem. Here is my source code:

```
#define _LARGEFILE_SOURCE
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define _FILE_OFFSET_BITS 64
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
/*-------------------------------------*/
//for file mapping in Linux
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/mman.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
/*-------------------------------------*/
#define PERMS 0600
#define NEW(type) (type *) malloc(sizeof(type))
#define FILE_MODE (S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)

void write_result(char *filename, char *data, long long length){

int fd, fq;

  fd = open(filename, O_RDWR|O_CREAT|O_LARGEFILE, 0644);

  if (fd < 0) {
  perror(filename);
  return -1;
  }

  if (ftruncate(fd, length) < 0)
  {
  printf("[%d]-ftruncate64 error: %s/n", errno, strerror(errno));
  close(fd);
  return 0;
  }

  fq = write (fd, data,length);

  close(fd);

  return;

}

main()
{
long long offset = 3000000000; // 3GB
char * ttt;
ttt = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *offset);
printf("length->%lld\n",strlen(ttt));  // length=0
memset (ttt,1,offset);
printf("length->%lld\n",strlen(ttt));  // length=3GB
write_result("test.big",ttt,offset);
return 1;
}
```

According to my test, the program can generate a file large than 2GB and can allocate such large memory as well. 
The weird thing happened when I tried to write data into the file. I checked the file and it is empty, which is supposed to be filled with 1.

Can any one be kind and help me with this?

Comment: Bump up the warning level on your compiler so a conversion from long long to unsigned int generates a decent diagnostic.

Comment: Big files are  usually not a language problem, but more often of the operating systen and/or the used file system. What are you using? Also your are not checking the return value of the write - which gives you the number of writen bytes.

Comment: You're using `strlen` on a char array that has just been allocated. Where would it get the terminating NULL from? This is also missing after using the memset. Again, no terminating NULL. You're (un)lucky your program hasn't crashed as a result of reading memory that was not allocated to it. This is not the problem you're asking about, though.

Comment: You are not checking the return value from write(). it *can* be less then the third argument. `man 2 write`

Comment: While most OSs can handle files > 2GB, a single write() call might not. Write to the file in chunks instead of one big gob of several GB..

Answer (score 0):

You need to read a little more about C strings and what `malloc` and `calloc` do.

In your original `main` `ttt` pointed to whatever garbage was in memory when `malloc` was called.  This means a nul terminator (the end marker of a C String, which is binary 0) could be anywhere in the garbage returned by `malloc`.

Also, since `malloc` does not touch every byte of the allocated memory (and you're asking for a lot) you could get sparse memory which means the memory is not actually physically available until it is read or written.

`calloc` allocates and fills the allocated memory with 0.  It is a little more prone to fail because of this (it touches every byte allocated, so if the OS left the allocation sparse it will not be sparse after `calloc` fills it.)

Here's your code with fixes for the above issues.
You should also always check the return value from `write` and react accordingly.  I'll leave that to you...

```
main()
{
    long long offset = 3000000000; // 3GB
    char * ttt;
    //ttt = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) *offset);
    ttt = (char *)calloc( sizeof( char ), offset ); // instead of malloc( ... )
    if( !ttt )
    {
        puts( "calloc failed, bye bye now!" );
        exit( 87 );
    }

    printf("length->%lld\n",strlen(ttt));  // length=0  (This now works as expected if calloc does not fail)
    memset( ttt, 1, offset );
    ttt[offset - 1] = 0;  // Now it's nul terminated and the printf below will work
    printf("length->%lld\n",strlen(ttt));  // length=3GB
    write_result("test.big",ttt,offset);
    return 1;
}
```

Note to Linux gurus...  I know sparse may not be the correct term.  Please correct me if I'm wrong as it's been a while since I've been buried in Linux minutiae. :)

Comment: Hi Jim, I need to thank you for posting your advice. :-) First of all, you are right about the '\0' issue. I should add an '\0' at the end. Moreover, maybe you are right about the calloc thing. But the thing is that both my original program and yours can 'printf' fine under linux and gcc, no matter with or without '\0' in the end. AND the main problem is still the same, which is this area of data still can not be saved into the file. So I wonder if have any other thoughts about this? Thanks in advance

Comment: @tzcoolman: I was hoping solving these problems would solve the others.  I have to admit to not reading real close...  I'll think about it a bit and post if I think of something.

Comment: @tzcoolman: I suggest preprocessing your source file and checking if the `write` function takes something other than `size_t` for the byte count.  Is there not a `write64`?  No Linux box here to check...

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're hitting the internal file system's limitation for the iDevice: [ios - Enterprise app with more than resource files of size 2GB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872699/ios-enterprise-app-with-more-than-resource-files-of-size-2gb)

2Gb+ files are simply not possible. If you need to store such amount of data you should consider using some other tools or write the file chunk manager.

Comment: what does this have to do with iPad?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and say that your problem may lay in memset().

The best thing to do here is, I think, after memset() ing it,

```
for (unsigned long i = 0; i < 3000000000; i++) {
  if (ttt[i] != 1) { printf("error in data at location %d", i); break; }
}
```

Once you've validated that the data you're trying to write is correct, then you should look into writing a smaller file such as 1GB and see if you have the same problems. Eliminate each and every possible variable and you will find the answer.