# App Size Limit and Finding the size of your app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

Okay, so i've read countless places saying the app size limit is either 20 mb and some say it's 50mb... which is it?

More importantly, my current app has an "estimate app store size" of 106.1mb in the Archive section of the Organizer. HOWEVER, when I distribute it to an ad-hoc file, it comes out as a .ipa which has the size of 48.3mb. Which one should I use, and I'm confused as to why they are so different.

Comment: I have apps which are greater than 1GB in size. The limit probably imposed when try to download from 3G.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The official (and reliably up to date) resource for this is the [Uploading Your Binary](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/SubmittingTheApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH33-SW4) section of the iTunes Connect Guide (expand the 'To begin the Ready to Upload Binary flow' section). At the time of this edit it states:

> **iOS App binary files can be as large as 2 GB**, but the executable file (app_name.app/app_name) cannot exceed 60 MB. However, consider download times when determining your app’s size. Minimize the file’s size as much as possible, keeping in mind that **there is a 100 MB limit for over-the-air downloads**.

Over-the-air download limit means apps below this threshold can be downloaded with a mobile data connection (anything above the limit requires a WiFi connection, or to be downloaded through iTunes on the computer). This is important as many users may not have ready access to WiFi and you don't want to prevent them from being able to get your app!

Also the .ipa is a compressed, encrypted zip file, whereas the archive is just a fully inflated package of the app, which is why the file sizes are different. The .ipa file size is the one that will be used in the App Store, so use that as your reference for total size. That said, the smaller you can make your app, obviously the happier the user will be!

Comment: Thank you for this, but I'm not sure why my generated .ipa file still has the similar file size as before. I switched to use .pvr.ccz from pure .pvr in turn it can reduce the overall file size pretty much, but at the end it's still the same. Am I missing anything here?

Comment: This might be dependent on the actual contents of your project. Do you have a lot of linked libraries / encrypted objects / etc? Some things can't be safely compressed so they're left untouched.

Comment: @Arian Do you know if an app can be larger than 2GB on a previsioned iOS device (we are working on an internal project so will not go via app store)?  Or to put another way, is the 2Gb limit an arbitrary figure placed by Apple or fundamental limit of hardware/software?

Comment: @RecycledSteel A good answer [on that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9872699/ios-enterprise-app-with-more-than-resource-files-of-size-2gb). I'd say it sounds possible up to 4GB but inadvisable, unless your app has some specialist purpose you might be way too heavy on bundled data... iDevices have pretty limited disk space!

Comment: I think you mean 50MB, not 50GB? You might want to correct that.

Comment: @AndrewFerrier Whoops, well spotted! Thanks, I've corrected it. A 50GB app would want to do some pretty magical stuff...

Answer (score 2):

Apple recently bumped up the size from 20 to 50 shortly after WWDC '12. I am not sure if it was officially announced, but was observed in the error message of larger apps.

[image]

Use the IPA size. The files sent from the app store are compressed. Perhaps the 106.1 is the uncompressed size, or it is a bug.

Answer (score 1):

### Today, Apple Increases Over-the-Air App Store Download Limit to 100MB.

[image]