# .ipa file have larger size in IOS

Tags: ios, ipa

i am working on iphone project. I am using some video file in my app by which the .ipa size is 152 MB .

I raed apple instruction for accepting an ipa file :

1. Apple support maximum size 2GB.
2. Excecutable size should not be grater then 60 MB.

but muy executable size is 162 MB. Can anyone tell me what can i do for accepting my app on itunes ? Please help.

Comment: Your executable ? What you mean ? .ipa file ?

Comment: The IPA it the total app size, including the resources. The executable if include in the IPA. Since your IPA is less then 2GB there should not be any problem. How do you know that your executable is 162MB?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11462687/app-size-limit-and-finding-the-size-of-your-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking at .app file instead of executable file.

.app, .ipa files are fine to be up to 2GB.

To find out exectuable file size - right click on .app or .ipa and choose "Show Package Contents". You can find exectuable with the same name as your application name (Unix exectuable file). It should be much much smaller.

Comment: yes. i am looking size of .app file. i think .app is the executable file. but when i checkout Unix Excecutable file (as defined by you) i found the size only 14 MB. Now please tell me is there is any problem for accepting app on itunes?

Comment: Nope - your good to go :) Mine is 32 MB and no problems with that.